# How to recover files encrypted by a ransomware (.nlah)

Tags: encryption, virus

A ransomware encrypted all my files with the extension **.nlah** 
I used Spyhunter 5 to scan my Windows 10 and delete the malwares.
Then I had to look for a way to recover my files with no success. This is the tool: **EMSIsoft: ransomware-decryption-tools**

I'm a doctor, and I save very important informations about my patients in that computer. So it's vital to recover those files. Can you help me please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6K3e.png)

Comment: Hello @Zack, you are likely to find answers on [https://security.stackexchange.com/](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [https://crypto.stackexchange.com/](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/). Stack Overflow is much more a programming site.

Answer (score 1):

It is almost impossible to decrypt the files without knowing  key and encryption mechanism.

Please make sure you have completed removed the ransomeware from your computer to avoid further damage.

If you have backup copy of your files then get it recovered from backup.

Comment: The virus has been completely deleted, and according to a friend, a local kety can be decrypted, but not an online key. So, if there is a way to do it please advice